# How to get the IPv6

Tags: ipv4, ipv6, network-discovery

I'm in a network that provides both IPv4 and IPv6 for the nodes, and i have the IPv4 of a machine. How can I find the IPv6 assigned for this machine?

Comment: That depends on the OS. End-device configurations are off-topic here. You should try to ask this question on [su].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the node is in your subnet and you can ping the IPv4 address do that, then do an arp -a and find the IPv4 address and the corresponding MAC address. then do a netsh int IPv6 neighbors and find the same MAC address as you did before and that would be the IPv6 address for the same node.

Comment: That'll only work if you've talked to it -- i.e. *already know the address*.

Comment: Worked for me, i just think that the command is missing the show part, nothing that i couldn't figure out.